# Filtro em coluna e cálculo de média

Tags: python

boa tarde
Estou estudando um datasets e preciso descobrir o preço médio de casas com 2 banheiros?

Utilizei o código:
**print(data[["bathrooms","price"]].groupby("bathrooms").mean())**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Sou totalmente leigo, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve funcionar
data['price'][data.bathrooms == 2].mean()

Comment: Perfeito , muito obrigado